# Spring Boot action with composite class and array request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to create a C# like composite class action with spring boot 2 with an array request.

My client will send the following:

```
Contet-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

With body:

```
company[name]:qwe
company[size]:1
address[country]:asd
address[address]:zxc
```

My action should be something like this:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<ResponseData<String>> action(CompanyCompositeRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

And the classes that I'd like to fill automatically:

```
class CompanyCompositeRequest {
    private Company company;
    private Address address;
}
class Company {
    private String name;
    private int size;
}
class Address {
    private String country;
    private String address;
}
```

And I'd like to run the Validator from the javax.validation on the properties of the classes in the composite.

Is that even possible? I tried a lot of version, and didn't find a working version, but I saw similar solutions. If I need to change the sent data from the client it's possible, for example in a JSON raw data, or something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by using the `@RequestBody` annotation in your controller method. It will make Spring automagically map the request body into your custom class.

See: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-requestbody-responsebody-example

Comment: It's working, but I have to use a raw JSON data instead of post the array from my original question.